# How many vtable and vpointers will be created in this example?

Tags: c++, vptr

Here is the program on vtables. Am I understanding is correct on vtables and v-pointers.

```
Class B
{
  public:

  virtual Void Hello()
  {
    cout<<"Hello Base";
  }
};

class D: public B    
{
  public:

  virtual void Hello()
  {
    cout<<"Hello Derived";
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  D *d1 = new D();
  D *d2 = new D();
  D *d3 = new D();

  return 0;
}
```

In my opinion, there will be two vtables and only one vptr. Am I correct on it?

Comment: Did you intend for D to inherit from B?

Comment: Oops, thanks! yes inheritance.

Comment: This is too localized- ain't nobody gonna be helped by the answer to this question. Just read the ABI specification for your compiler- whichever compiler and ABI that is that you didn't specify- and it will define the answer.

Comment: No vtables and no vptrs will be created by an implementation that uses no vtables, or by an implementation that eliminates vtables during a whole-program optimization pass.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The standard does not define how virtual functions are actually implemented, only how they should behave. So what you are asking for entirely depends on the compiler you are using.

---

GCC will in theory most likely create two vtables (one for `B` and one for `D`) and three vptrs (one for each of the object instances `d1`, `d2`, `d3`).

Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table

Comment: How it will behave on gcc?

Comment: Whilst this is true, it's also totally unhelpful and cannot accurately answer his question.Not that this is your fault since his question is unanswerable, but that's another matter.

Comment: @DeadMG: Why is it unhelpful? I made a statement about the general case and gave some hints on a specific case.

Comment: Compile it with gcc and see for yourself.

Comment: The statement about the general case is "Your question is unanswerable in the general case (but this is totally an answer for the general case anyway)", which we already knew, and his question does not identify a specific case.

Comment: @DeadMG: It identifies the specific case of "an implementation using vtables and vptrs", which is enough for all but the most anal of pedants to answer the question.

Answer (score 8):

You might find the implementation detail in your compiler documentation.
It may vary from version to version, even between platforms.

For gcc on Linux, it is likely that each D instance will need its vptr and one vtable.

You have 3 instances of D:

- Each will have its vptr -> 3 vptr
- Each points to the same vtable.

So 3 vptr and 1 vtable (+1 vtable for B, which is useless here).

Again this is an *implementation detail*, and in your very simple case it is subject to compiler optimisations.

Comment: You've answered an unanswerable question by answering some specific sub-case of it. That does not answer the question.

Comment: I dont agree, the OP specified gcc, and gcc implementation is documented. Answering the question is helpful from a cultural perspective, even if you limit youself to a specific subcase of it. Anyway thanks for replying.

Answer (score 5):

In a typical vtable-based implementation of virtual polymorphism, there will be:

- one vtable per *class*, containing the virtual function pointers and other metadata for that class;
- one vptr per *object*, pointing to the vtable for that object's dynamic class type.

So here there will be two vtables (for `B` and `D`) and three vptrs (in `*d1`, `*d2` and `*d3`). Unless the compiler notices that you're not using the objects an eliminates them altogether.